# How can we get the text of the submenu context created when it is pressed

Tags: java, contextmenu, e4

I have created a context menu bar with submenus.i have generated the submenus by using for loop
from the list.so when i press any one the submenu item generated i should get the text of the submenu item pressed.so how can we do it.I have only one run method inside the submenu but each submenu items perform different functionality.so how different functionality can be handled by one run method.

for ex

```
main menu->submenu1
         ->submenu2
         ->submenu3
```

so if i press submenu 2 i should get the string of the submenu item pressed and respective method should be called as it has only one run method

the code for generating context menu is as follows

```
MenuManager contextMenu = new MenuManager("#ViewerMenu"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        contextMenu.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);

        contextMenu.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager mgr) {

                fillContextMenu(mgr);
                // IMenuManager submenu = new MenuManager("Sub menu title");
                // submenu.add(someaction);

            }
        });

 protected void fillContextMenu(final IMenuManager contextMenu) {

    IMenuManager submenu = new MenuManager("Add  Case");

    List<String> testCases = new ArrayList<>();
    testCases.addAll(TestCases.testCaseNames);
    for (String item : testCases)
    {
      System.out.println("item is"+item);
      submenu.add(new Action(item) {
      @Override
       public void run()
         {
                        // implement this
          }
          });
        }

        contextMenu.add(submenu);


        }
```

So how can this be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getText()` method of `Action` returns the menu text.

So:

```
 submenu.add(new Action(item) {
  @Override
   public void run()
     {
       String itemText = getText();

       ...
     }
```

Comment: I tried but it is giving errors.i need the text when it is pressed.For action there is no method called gettEXT().pLEASE HELP ME

Comment: 'giving errors' is not a helpful description of a problem. `getText` is the only thing available.

Comment: can you explain where to use this method in the above code so that it will be helpful